# How do I control a movieclip using a button?

Tags: actionscript-3

Actionscript newbie. 
Actionscript 3.0
Started by following the tutorial at http://republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/basicwebsite/
Everything works fine as long as the code remains in the Flash file. It is when I move it to an external file I have an issue.

I have the following code on my action layer keyframe:

```
    stop();

function goHome (e:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("Home");
}
home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goHome);

function goAbout (e:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("About");
}
about_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goAbout);

function goLinks (e:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("Links");
}
links_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goLinks);

function goContact (e:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("Contact");
}
contact_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goContact);
```

Everything works fine but I want to move the code to an external as3 file and am running into issues.

I have added the Document class "site1" and that is the name of my external file. I removed the code from my flash file keyframe and moved it to the external file.

Here is the code as it appears in my site1.as

```
    package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;

public class button extends MovieClip{

    public function button() {
        function goHome (e:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("Home");
}
home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goHome);

function goAbout (e:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("About");
}
about_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goAbout);

function goLinks (e:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("Links");
}
links_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goLinks);

function goContact (e:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("Contact");
}
contact_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goContact);
    }
}
}
```

The problem is when I publish my Flash file it just keeps looping and not pausing for a button click.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As well as paying attention the answers given, try adding a `stop();` as an action on frame 1 of the timeline (or whatever frame you need a stop). This will stop the movie playing through all frames and looping but instead can go to frame labels via button clicks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your class and file with the same name.   I suggest the following code.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class YourClassName extends MovieClip
    {
        public function YourClassName() {
            home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goHome);
            about_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goAbout);
            links_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goLinks);
            contact_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goContact);          
        }

        private function goHome(e:MouseEvent):void {
            gotoAndStop("Home");
        }       

        private function goAbout(e:MouseEvent):void {
            gotoAndStop("About");
        }

        private function goLinks(e:MouseEvent):void {
            gotoAndStop("Links");
        }

        private function goContact(e:MouseEvent):void {
            gotoAndStop("Contact");
        }

    }
}
```

AS3 is more explicit than AS2.  I suggest you use `private` / `public` accessors.

EDIT.

'button' is not a really good class name, but it will work.

1) name your file, class and constructor : 'button' :

```
public class button extends MovieClip

public function button()
```

2) be sure that your linkage is good!  Meaning : if you want to control your whole Movie with this class, change the document "Class" name for `button` , if you want to control only a MovieClip from your library, drag it on your stage, check "Export for action script", and change your "Class" value for `button`.

Think that with this method, you don't need any instance name. The class linkage is enough in this case.

Ref :

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Class.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b8ea63-7fee.html

Comment: This gives me the following error "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at button()"

Comment: See my EDIT.  I think your question was more about "How can I do a Document linkage or Class linkage with AS3 ?". If I did understand correctly the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A class is made up of properties and functions: usually a constructor, which runs as soon as the class is instantiated (which in document classes is as soon as the application runs), and then other functions which are called in different ways.

What you've done is that you've put all your functions *within* the constructor: not good. That's putting a function in a function, you just don't do that (although technically, you could make anonymous functions, but that's a different story).

In addition, your event listeners should be added within the constructor. Adding event listeners is calling a function, and (to my knowledge) you can't call functions from a class outside of other functions.

Basically, you should just take your functions out of the constructor, like this:

```
package{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class button extends MovieClip{

        public function button() {
            home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goHome);
            about_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goAbout);
            links_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goLinks);
            contact_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goContact);
        }

        function goHome (e:MouseEvent):void{
            gotoAndStop("Home");
        }

        function goAbout (e:MouseEvent):void{
            gotoAndStop("About");
        }

        function goLinks (e:MouseEvent):void{
            gotoAndStop("Links");
        }

        function goContact (e:MouseEvent):void{
            gotoAndStop("Contact");
        }
    }
}
```

Another thing is that the file name should be identical to the class name. That is, your document class should be called `button.as` instead of `site1.as`. I'm not completely sure if it's 100% necessary in the Flash IDE (been a while since I've used it) since it didn't give an error, but even if it isn't it's good practice.

It'd be a good idea to study up on how classes work, and document classes specifically. [Here's a kirupa tutorial on classes](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/as3/classes_as3_pg1.htm), and [here's an ActiveTuts+ tutorial on document classes](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/quick-tip-how-to-use-a-document-class-in-flash/).

Comment: I just now rectified my code as I forgot to add the event listeners to the constructor. However Eric's answer has a point about specifying the scope of functions with `private`/`public` accessors: while they aren't essentially, it's generally good practice to specify them for clarity, if nothing else.